# Non-tail recursion within a for loop

Tags: python, recursion

> Given an array of numbers, find the length of the longest increasing subsequence in the array. The subsequence does not necessarily have to be contiguous.
>
> For example, given the array [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15], the longest increasing subsequence has length 6: it is 0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15.

One of the solutions to the above problem uses non-tail recursion within a for loop, and I am having trouble making sense of it. I don't understand when the code after the recursive call in the for loop is executed, and I can't visualize the entire execution process of the whole solution.

```
def longest_increasing_subsequence(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return 1

    max_ending_here = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        ending_at_i = longest_increasing_subsequence(arr[:i])
        if arr[-1] > arr[i - 1] and ending_at_i + 1 > max_ending_here:
            max_ending_here = ending_at_i + 1
    return max_ending_here
```

The description of the solution is as follows:

> Assume that we already have a function that gives us the length of the longest increasing subsequence. Then we’ll try to feed some part of our input array back to it and try to extend the result. Our base cases are: the empty list, returning 0, and an array with one element, returning 1.
>
> Then,
>
> - For every index `i` up until the second to last element, calculate `longest_increasing_subsequence` up to there.
> - We can only extend the result with the last element if our last element is greater than `arr[i]` (since otherwise, it’s not increasing).
> - Keep track of the largest result.

Source: https://www.dailycodingproblem.com/blog/longest-increasing-subsequence/

---

**EDITS**:

What I mean by I don't understand when the code after the recursive call in the for loop is executed. Here is my understanding:

0. Some code calls `lis([0, 8, 4, 12, 2])`.
1. `arr = [0, 8, 4, 12, 2]` doesn't meet either of the two base cases.
2. The for loop makes the first call when `i = 0` in the line `ending_at_i = lis([])`. This is the first base case, so it returns 0. I can't understand why control doesn't return to the for loop so that `ending_at_i` is set to 0, and the if condition is executed (because it surely isn't checked else `[][-1]` would throw an error), after which we can move on to the for loop making the second call when `i = 1`, third call when `i = 2` which would branch into two calls, and so on.

Comment: `arr[:i]` is immediately linear, so this is a very inefficient solution right off the bat. If one really needs to use recursion for some reason (already not a good choice for this problem), they should pass an index to the recursive call rather than copying the list over and over again.

Comment: Can you clarify what you do not understand about this? It's not really clear whether you are having a problem with recursion in general or this specific problem. As for "I don't understand when the code after the recursive call in the for loop is executed" – it is executed after the recursive call.

Comment: @ggorlen I can see that it's inefficient. What I want is to understand it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I understand alright general recursion patterns, such as those used in place of iteration, parsing binary trees, etc. The pattern used here doesn't seem to fall in the patterns I know though. It might also be true that I think I know those patterns when I actually don't know them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how this function works.  Fist, it handles the degenerate cases where the list length is 0 or 1.

It then looks for the solution when the list length is >= 2.  There are two possibilities for the longest sequence:  (1) It may contain the last number in the list, or (2) It may not contain the last number in the list.

For case (1), if the last number in the list is in the longest sequence, then the number before it in the longest sequence must be one of the earlier numbers.  Suppose the number before it in the sequence is at position x.  Then the longest sequence is the longest sequence taken from the numbers in the list up to and including x, plus the last number in the list.  So it recurses on all of the possible positions of x, which are 0 through the list length minus 2.  It iterates `i` over `range(len(arr))`, which is 0 through `len(arr)-1)`.  But it then uses `i` as the upper bound in the slice, so the last element in the slice corresponds to indices `-1` through `len(arr)-2`.  In the case of `-1`, this is an empty slice, which handles the case where all values in the list before the last are >= the last element.

This handles case (1).  For case (2), we just need to find the largest sequence from the sublist that excludes the last element.  However, this check is missing from the posted code, which is why the wrong answer is given for a list like `[1, 2, 3, 0]`:

```
>>> longest_increasing_subsequence([1, 2, 3, 0])
0
>>>
```

Obviously the correct answer in this case is `3`, not `0`.  This is fairly easy to fix, but somehow was left out of the posted version.

Also, as others have pointed out, creating a new slice each time it recurses is unnecessary and inefficient.  All that's needed is to pass the length of the sublist to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the author of the blog [source at the end of the question] missed the check for case (2).

Comment: @cipher Yes I was surprised to notice that.  I was in the process of describing that check, which seemed obvious to me, but when I referred back to the code I saw that it was absent!  Also note that there are more efficient algorithms for solving this problem than the one used here.

Comment: I saw the efficient solutions. I wanted to understand the mechanism of this solution that uses recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (hopefully good enough) explanation:

`ending_at_i` = the length of the LIS when you clip `arr` at the `i-th` index (that is, considering elements `arr[0], arr[1], ..., arr[i-1]`.

## `if arr[-1] > arr[i - 1] and ending_at_i + 1 > max_ending_here`

`if arr[-1] > arr[i - 1]` = if the last element of `arr` is greater than the last element of the part of `arr` correponding to `ending_at_i`

`if ending_at_i + 1 > max_ending_here` = if appending the last element of `arr` to the LIS found during computing `ending_at_i` is larger than the current best LIS

The recursive step is then:

1. Let an oracle tell you the length of the LIS in `arr[:i]` (= `arr[0], arr[1], ..., arr[i-1]`)

   - realize that, if the last element of `arr`, that is, `arr[-1]`, is larger than the last element of `arr[:i]`, then whatever the LIS inside `arr[:i]` was, if you take it and append `arr[-1]`, it will still be an LIS, except that it will be one element larger
2. Check whether `arr[-1]` is actually larger than `arr[i-1]`, (= `arr[:i][-1]`)
3. Check whether appending `arr[-1]` to the LIS of `arr[:i]` creates the new optimal solution
4. Repeat 1., 2., 3. `for i in range(len(arr))`.
5. The result will be the knowledge of the length of the LIS inside `arr`.

All that being said, since the recursive substep of this algorithm runs in `O(n)`, there are very few worse feasible solutions to the problem.

You tagged `dynamic programming`, however, this is precisely the anti-example of such. `Dynamic programming` lets you reuse the solutions to subproblems, which is precisely what this algorithm doesn't do, hence wasting time. Check out a DP solution instead.